# value toDS is not a member of org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD

Tags: scala, hadoop, apache-spark, dataset, rdd

I am trying to write sample Apache Spark program that converts RDD to Dataset. But in that process, I am getting compile time error.

Here is my sample code and error:

**code:**

```
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset

object Hello {

  case class Person(name: String, age: Int)

  def main(args: Array[String]){
    val conf = new SparkConf()
      .setAppName("first example")
      .setMaster("local")
    val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
    val peopleRDD: RDD[Person] = sc.parallelize(Seq(Person("John", 27)))
    val people = peopleRDD.toDS
  }
}
```

**and my error is:**

```
value toDS is not a member of org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[Person]
```

I have added Spark core and spark SQL jars.

and my versions are:

Spark 1.6.2

scala 2.10

Answer (score 11, accepted):

## Spark version < 2.x

`toDS` is available with `sqlContext.implicits._`

```
val sqlContext = new SQLContext(sc);
import sqlContext.implicits._
val people = peopleRDD.toDS()
```

## Spark version >= 2.x

```
val spark: SparkSession = SparkSession.builder
  .config(conf)
  .getOrCreate;

import spark.implicits._
val people = peopleRDD.toDS()
```

HIH

Answer (score 11):

There are two mistakes I can see in your code.

First you have to `import sqlContext.implicits._` as `toDS` and `toDF` are defined in implicits of sqlContext.

Second is that `case class` should be defined outside class scope where the case class is being used otherwise `task not serializable exception` will occur

Complete solution is as following

```
    import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
    import org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD
    import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
    import org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset

    object Hello {
      def main(args: Array[String]){
      val conf = new SparkConf()
      .setAppName("first example")
      .setMaster("local")
      val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
      val sqlContext = new SQLContext(sc)

      import sqlContext.implicits._
      val peopleRDD: RDD[Person] = sc.parallelize(Seq(Person("John", 27)))
      val people = peopleRDD.toDS
      people.show(false)
      }
    }
    case class Person(name: String, age: Int)
```

Comment: Defining case class inside the scope may be a really annoying issue in this case. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: `import spark.implicits._` failed for me until I moved the case class outside of the object. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The exact answer is you importing both,

```
import spark.implicits._ 

import sqlContext.implicits._
```

this is causing the issue, remove any 1 of those, you wont face issue like this

Comment: Hi, Jodu. Please wrap code in code blocks for clarity ([see documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code)).